# PickerView not working

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am using UIPickerView to pick from selected data.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 640, 320, 200)];
myPickerView.delegate = self;
myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[self.view addSubview:myPickerView];
UIToolbar  *toolBar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
[toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(changeDateFromLabel:)];
toolBar.items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:barButtonDone,nil];
barButtonDone.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
}
```

and

```
 (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
// Handle the selection
NSLog(@"%d",row);
lbl.text=[ary objectAtIndex:row];
}

// tell the picker how many rows are available for a given component
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
NSUInteger numRows = 5;

return numRows;
}

// tell the picker how many components it will have
 - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
return 1;
 }
 - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

UILabel* tView = (UILabel*)view;
if (!tView){
    tView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    // Setup label properties - frame, font, colors etc
    tView.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
    //adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property to YES
   // tView.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
}
// Fill the label text here
tView.text=[ary objectAtIndex:row];
[tView setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
[tView setNumberOfLines:0];
return tView;
 }
```

and I am moving view up when user click on label(label tap event):

```
-(void)labelTap{
v1.hidden=NO;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect frm;
                     frm=self.view.frame;
                     frm.origin.y=frm.origin.y-400;
                     self.view.frame=frm;
                    // self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, -30, 320, 200);
                     //v1.frame=CGRectMake(0, 360, 320, 200);
                     // v1.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     if(finished)  {NSLog(@"Finished end !!!!!");}
                 }];

 }
```

But when I tap on label UIPickerView display but I am unable to pick data from it. It is just displaying UIPickerView.

Comment: You use tView, and use didSelectRow: in lbl.
In which label you used?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the datasource as well.

```
myPickerView.datasource = self;
```

Answer (score 2):

In **.h** file, make sure you have added `UIPickerViewDataSource` & `UIPickerViewDelegate` and in **.m** file, `picker.dataSource = Self;` & `picker.delegate = Self` after you allocate the `UIPickerView` object.

Note:- I am unable to comment on this question that's why mentioning this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to define **UIPickerViewDatasource** in your ViewController's header,

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
```

2) In `- (void)viewDidLoad` you need to do `myPickerView.datasource = self;` with `myPickerView.delegate = self;`

3) I hope you are populating your datasource i.e. **ary** array as I am unable to see that part in the code you pasted.

Comment: but if i add picker view to another view and then add that view as subview and run application then it is working without decalring datasource.